# Making compile time variations of a member function for raw pointers, smart pointers and values

Tags: c++, templates

I have class like below. Which I encapsulate vector to get rid of for loops. Working example can be found in [link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tSgHEXyvHQeXtHUM)(thanks to help in comment section)

```
    template<class T, class U>
    std::shared_ptr<T> Cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& spObject )   // rename from CastTerrainObject
    {
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(spObject);
    }

    template<class T, class U>
    T Cast( U* r)
    {
        return dynamic_cast<T>(r);
    }

    template<typename value> 
    struct A 
    {

        template < typename T, typename F >
        T Find( F filterFunction)
        {
            return DoFind<T>(filterFunction, std::is_pointer<T>());
        }

        template < typename T, typename F >
        T DoFind( F filterFunction, std::true_type)
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < iteratableList.size(); i++)
            {
                auto castedTerrain = Cast<T>(iteratableList[i]);
                if ( castedTerrain && filterFunction(castedTerrain) )
                    return iteratableList[i];
            }
            return T();
        }


        template < typename T, typename F >
        T DoFind( F filterFunction, std::false_type)
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < iteratableList.size(); i++)
            {
                auto castedTerrain =  Cast<typename T::element_type>(iteratableList[i]);
                if ( castedTerrain && filterFunction(castedTerrain) )
                    return iteratableList[i];
            }
            return T();
        }

        std::vector<value> iteratableList;
    }
```

My class is working good for smart pointers

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> names = {  make_shared("needle"), make_shared("manyOtherNames") } ; 
A<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> iterateable{ names }; 
iterateable.Find<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>([] ( std::shared_ptr<std::string> ){ return *in == "needle";});
```

and for raw pointers

```
std::vector<std::string*> names = {  new std::string("needle"), new std::string("manyOtherNames") } ; 
A<std::string*> iterateable{ names }; 
iterateable.Find<std::string*>([] ( std::string* in ){ return *in == "needle";});
```

But now I want to use it with values as well like(std::string is just a example I want my class to work with any non pointer and non smart pointer type as well) :

```
std::vector<std::string> names = {  "needle", "manyOtherNames" } ; 
A<std::string> iterateable{ names }; 
iterateable.Find<std::string>([] ( std::string in ){ return in == "needle";});
```

I need one more DoFind but I couldn't see a type trait for my case. 
How can I organize my code to achieve what I need. I am restricted to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Can you add an example for all your use cases (pointer, smart pointer, value type)? I don't really get what you're trying to do

Comment: Hope it looks better now.

Comment: Nope, your code does not work: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WRKPcDp5nwcRyc0k

Comment: I forgot the function Cast. It compiles now http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tSgHEXyvHQeXtHUM

Comment: There is not anything like std::is_smartPtr, If there would I would come up with a solution which would a bit long like I wrote the same code three times .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. Your lambdas are not returning a boolean:

This:

```
[] ( std::string in ){ in == "needle";}
```

Should be:

```
[] ( std::string in ){ return in == "needle";}
```

2. Why are you trying to perform a `dynamic_cast` on a non-pointer type? use `static_cast` for those.

Change this:

```
Cast<typename T::element_type>(iteratableList[i]);
```

into this:

```
static_cast<T>(iteratableList[i]);
```

3. However, since you need to keep your `Cast` function, it is enough to define another overload to accept a value, leaving us with three versions.

Notice that I modified your `shared_ptr` version because it was incorrect.

```
template<class T, class U>
T Cast(const U& r)
{
    return static_cast<T>(r);
}

template<class T, class U>
T Cast(const std::shared_ptr<U>& spObject)
{
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<typename T::element_type>(spObject);
}

template<class T, class U>
T Cast( U* r)
{
    return dynamic_cast<T>(r);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345b14a586ca4b44)

Comment: Thanks I corrected. But this wasn't what I were asking for. I am trying to avoid the dynamic cast for the value type "in compile time"  and that is what I am asking for actually.

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: I don't completely understand. You don't have to dynamic cast anything. Can you show an "ideal" code for "avoiding the dynamic cast for the value type in compile time"?

Comment: I am trying to make class work for pointers, shared_pointer and values.But if I try to make my class work with values because of this dynamic cast compile is failing. I am trying to avoid dynamic casting line only for non pointer types in compiler time

Comment: I am sure this is something not hard but I am not asking the question correctly I am trying my best though. Please correct me if you can about terms etc..

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: Yes of course, did you look at my example? You can safely remove the call to `Cast` for non-pointer types, because you don't want to by doing dynamic casts on them anyway. A simple `static_cast` is good enough. I have an idea: Modify the code in my "Live Demo" so that the code looks like how you want it to be (it's okay if it doesn't compile), and then I can go in and see what the misunderstanding is.

Comment: Yes but just for string case it might seem ok to use static case. But in my project this I really need dynamic_cast. It can't be removed for pointer types. That is why I need to branch out to a thrid DoFind function on compile time

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: In my example I didn't remove `dynamic_cast` for pointer types. [Is this code not what you need?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fb80966f51bef00)

Comment: I am sorry but it is not, you are using static_cast instead Cast method. std::pointer  return false for  smart pointer and that is why your code is removing dynamic cast for smart pointer types

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: Did you mean [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345b14a586ca4b44)? The issue was that you were actually trying to construct a `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<T>> instead of a `shared_ptr<T>`

Comment: I think 3rd option you wrote in the answer will work. I am trying it now.